# Can I do inline embedding for Youtube videos to Android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, youtube

Can I do inline embedding for Youtube videos to Android devices? When I had embed a Youtube video on a webpage, Android devices plays automatically in native player. Can I prevent native player?

**Update:** As of March 2018, viewing embedded YouTube videos are slightly better, because of general improvement of Android base. Videos are playing in the default player of client's browser now. But using the default YouTube player is still impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) allows you to embed YouTube videos within your application as either a standalone `Activity` (via [YouTubeStandalonePlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer)) or as a `Fragment` added to an existing `Activity` (via [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)) or even just as a View (via [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView)). Check out the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/#Getting_Started) to get it set up for your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the video played on youtube's default player, embed within iframe as described on you tube [developer's site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo).

If you are unable to use it, install a html5 player and put your link in it. [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) is an example.

If you provide a link to the video, it will always open up in native player irrespective of device.

Comment: "If you want to have the video played on youtube's default player, embed within iframe as described on you tube developer's site." I did it but video plays in Android's native player, again.